Regular expression for L = {w|w doesn't contain the substring 110} over the alphabet Σ = {0,1}

Consider the language L = {w|w doesn't contain the substring 110} over the alphabet Σ = {0,1}
Write the regular expression

Currently I have the regular expression as 0*(10*10)*1*
But the autograder says that is wrong and I am not sure how to fix it.
Autograder results:
Running command: $ timeout 15 python3 unit_tests/unit_test_prob_1_18f.py
UNEXPECTED RESULT ON THESE INPUTS: ['10', '010', '100', '101', '0010', '0100', '0101', '1000', '1001', '1011', ...]
Test for: unit_test_prob_1_18f.py
    This test gave you 0 more points

Autograder code:
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
from automata.fa.nfa import NFA
import re

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

### Open files and populate lists ###
accept_file = open("unit_tests/inputs/1_6f_accepts.txt", "r")
reject_file = open("unit_tests/inputs/1_6f_rejects.txt", "r")
accept_list = accept_file.readlines()
reject_list = reject_file.readlines()

### Remove newlines ###
for i in range(len(accept_list)):
    accept_list[i] = accept_list[i][:-1]
for i in range(len(reject_list)):
    reject_list[i] = reject_list[i][:-1]

### Test Inputs ###
from prob_1_18f import prob_1_18f
test_machine = NFA.from_regex(prob_1_18f, input_symbols={'0', '1'})

UNEXPECTED = []

for w in accept_list:
    if w not in test_machine:
        UNEXPECTED.append(w)

for w in reject_list:
    if w in test_machine:
        UNEXPECTED.append(w)

### Not Allowing automata-lib Functions ###
pattern = "accepts_input|copy|read_input|read_input_stepwise|validate|iter_transitions|show_diagram|cardinality|clear_cache|complement|count_mod|count_words_of_length|difference|empty_language|from_finite_language|from_nfa|from_prefix|from_subsequence|from_substring|from_substrings|from_suffix|intersection|isdisjoint|isempty|isfinite|issubset|issuperset|iter_transitions|maximum_word_length|minify|minimum_word_length|nth_from_end|nth_from_start|of_length|predecessor|predecessors|random_word|read_input_stepwise|successor|successors|symmetric_difference|to_complete|to_partial|union|universal_language|validate|words_of_length|concatenate|edit_distance|eliminate_lambda|from_dfa|from_regex|intersection|iter_transitions|kleene_star|left_quotient|option|read_input_stepwise|reverse|right_quotient|shuffle_product|union|validate|from_dfa|from_nfa|iter_transitions|to_regex|validate|isequal|issubset|issuperset|validate"
with open("prob_1_18f.py","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            print("automata-lib funcs not allowed for this assignment")
            print(f"-->{line[:-1]}")
            sys.exit(1)

if len(UNEXPECTED) > 0:
    print("UNEXPECTED RESULT ON THESE INPUTS: ", end="")
    if len(UNEXPECTED) > 10:
        print("[", end="")
        for i in range(9):
            print(f"\'{UNEXPECTED[i]}\'", end=", ")
        print(f"\'{UNEXPECTED[9]}\


Can I have the grader to test?

@yshavit Where did you get that "takes too long" phrase?

@phuc16102001 I just attached it to the original post

@DaneShuler Are there any constraints, or would any regex allowed by Python's re work for you?

@InSync I just attached the autograder code to my original post so as long as it passes that then it is good.

As a side note, using .strip is a much safer way to remove newlines then arbitrarily removing the last character.

Your code will accept "110".  No 0s, then a 1 with no 0s followed by 1 0, and no 1s.

@InSync I misread the "timeout" in the original

Your regular expression accepts 110, (in particular with the part 10*10 where 0* accepts ε).
No occurrence of 110 is equivalent to saying that after the first occurrence of 11 (if any) there should be no more zeroes in the rest of the input.
We can represent this with the following DFA:

We have a start state which represents the state where the previous input symbol (if any) was not 1.
The next state is where the number of consecutive 1 symbols amounts to one.
The third state is where the number of consecutive 1 symbols is two or more.
The rightmost state is where the rule was violated and a 0 followed a sequence of two (or more) 1 symbols. It is a non-accept state with no outgoing transitions: a sink.
We can translate that DFA to this regular expression:
(0|10)*1*

